# Nested multiple select boxes

Tags: jquery, user-interface, nested, element

I've made a div based `<select />` boxes to may them work as cross-browser ui.
The problem is, that i can't find out how to filter nested selectboxes inside other selectboxes. I mean, make them work only for clicked element, and not for childs.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aspirinemaga/ejyRR/

Would like to make them work in that way:

```
<div class="gui-selectbox">
  SELECTBOX1
  <div class="gui-selectbox">SELECTBOX2</div>
</div>
```

I know it's easy, but i can't find out the right selector to make it work. Thanks in advance for your help and time.

**EDIT** - 2nd demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aspirinemaga/ejyRR/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of issues here

1. Your opening click event should be on `.gui-selectbox-button`, not `.gui-selectbox` and it should return false to ensure it doesn't propagate.
2. You are always calling `gui_selectbox_closeAll`. You need to be closing all that *are not parents of target*. Fixed by `$('.gui-selectbox-dialog:visible').not($(event.target).parents('.gui-selectbox-dialog'))`. Do similar thing for the button.
3. Your `gui_selectbox_listAction` is setting value for **all** the parents. You should be using `closest()` there instead.

Comment: Trying to do what are you said, but can't succeed.1st and 2nd issue is ok, but the third one I can't resolve. Here is a **[link](http://jsfiddle.net/aspirinemaga/ejyRR/2/)**. Could you please provide me a code for the third one? Thank you

Comment: Just replace `parents()` call with `closest()`.

Comment: seems to be something wrong in other part of the code, because it's not working.

Comment: can't figure how to make it work. i've did it, but it's now working.